# Select all body elements except two ids

Tags: css

I need to select all body elements except two ids and apply css rules to them. I am using this code and it works for one id, but when second one is added the code does not work anymore. 
This code works:

```
body>*:not(#frm){
filter: blur(3px);
pointer-events: none;
}
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
body>*:not(#frm,#dte2){
  filter: blur(3px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and this

```
body>*:not(#frm),(#dte){
  filter: blur(3px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

So my question is how do you select 2 ids?

Comment: body>*:not(#frm),body>*:not(#dte){

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with selecting *two* IDs for a [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) negation is that `#frm` would match the criteria for not being `#dte`, and `#dte` would match the criteria for not being `#frm`.

What you need to do is chain two `:not()` pseudo-selectors together as `body>*:not(#frm):not(#dte)`:

```css
body>*:not(#frm):not(#dte) {
  filter: blur(3px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="frm">Frm</div>
  <div id="dte">Dte</div>
  <div id="other">Other</div>
</body>
```